# To load layer on leaflet even on offline

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet

I'm using leaflet map in my ionic application.

On offline, by default, open street map layer loads but when changing the zoom level, the map disappears.

How can I get the map to show when zoomed offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download (pre-cache) the tile images to work with offline mode.

Download the tiles at the zoom levels you want. Map data is quite large and so you may want to limit to a small subset of zoom levels, or a geographic boundary (a city, country, etc.)

OSM's specific tile usage policy is here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy But the part that applies to your app is this:

> In particular, downloading significant areas of tiles at zoom levels
>   17 and higher for offline or later usage is forbidden without prior
>   consultation with a System Administrator.

That page also lists numerous "free" tile providers. Because I expect it to change "significantly" over time, I'm not gonna copy and paste it for you.

Unless you enter into some kind of contract/agreement with the tile provider, you may need to render your own or find a different tile service that will allow you to pre-cache tiles.

The details for downloading map data that can be rendered as tiles can be found on the OSM website: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data

There are multiple ways to get the data from OSM, but these services and options will undoubtedly change over time so I think it safest to just refer to their website (google "download open street map data" if above link is broken).

I have used a .NET library called BruTile to manage the tile cache. But basically it is just a bunch of image files organized in a zoom/grid structure.

It would also be good for you to google search topics such as "ionic leaflet tile cache" and "pre cache map tiles ionic" and such. There isn't a lot out there yet, but this is a growing area of development.

**Thoughts regarding mobile apps**

If you are deploying to mobile devices it probably doesn't make sense to deploy the pre-cached tiles because (a) they will become out of date and require constant upkeep, and (b) large file size resulting in slow downloads. It would be better to download tiles while online after the app is installed.

Windows and Android phones both allow download of offline map data in their maps apps. It may be possible to leverage that data. Otherwise you would make your app work similarly: prompt user to download maps for their region, and then find a way to reasonably specify the region (geographic area) for which they need maps. It is also a good idea to let the user know how much data will be downloaded for metered data plans and device storage.

It also would be better for you to use a server other than the OSM servers, such as a paid Microsoft or MapQuest or Bing account. The OSM servers aren't capable of handling production load across every SPA that wants maps to work offline. Better to rely on the device's capabilities and built-in maps app if possible. Amazon and Azure (for example) services may be feasible for this. If you wrote your own program to run as a service on your own sever it could pre-cache tiles from the tile service (thus reducing your usage fees and server load) and then the apps would just get map data from your server. This also gives you the opportunity to get creative with your own custom tiles.

Comment: You should insist on the difference between OSM **data** and **tiles**. Downloading data is free, but you have to use a rendering engine before you can use it (most probably as raster tiles) in Leaflet. Downloading tiles is a different story. It is called _bulk downloading_ / tiles _scraping_ and it is usually discouraged / forbidden by free services like OSM (see the [Tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy)). Even paid services might restrict it, or allow only end-user triggered download (no pre-cache).

Comment: ^^ there ya go. Like ghybs says you are subject to whatever usage policy the service defines. There are various tools you can use to render tiles from the data. Projects I have worked on usually rely on an ESRI server that transforms map data into tiles (OSM "ways" rendered as roads, etc.), and user's device downloads the ESRI tiles. I've used BruTile for .NET but had to do a proprietary solution for iOS. I think Microsoft made Xamarin dev licenses free recently and so that may an option. Can't really speak to others, but again: you just need some structure leaflet can work with, like `z/x/y`